# postgresql: whats wrong in my sql statement of altering a column in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table

I am trying to alter a tables column with a default value of -11 and it can be null

```
ALTER TABLE devicedata ALTER COLUMN "weather" smallint NULL DEFAULT -11 ;
```

it says error

[image]

Comment: `type` ????????????

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres the [syntax for this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) is:

```
alter table device_data alter column wheather type smallint;
```

Then you can change the `default`:

```
alter table device_data alter column wheather set default 10;
```

The `column` keyword is optional.